# Rotation of axes

Tags: geometry, rotations

Is it possible to rotate the axes along a point that is NOT lying on the axes? For example, consider the point C(u,v) where $u,v \neq 0$. Can I rotate the axes about this point? 
In my mind, this seems very possible. Also, the way I visualize it, I would say that the coordinates of point C with respect to the new axes will remain (u,v). Am I correct in saying so?

Comment: Translate so that $(u,v)$ becomes the origin, rotate, then translate back.

Comment: To answer the second part of your question, yes, the coordinates of the point of rotation will remain the same. (It is a *fixed point*.) In a non-trivial rotation (i.e., a rotation by an angle that is not a multiple of $2\pi$), the point of rotation is the only fixed point.

Comment: @JonathanS. Aha.... So here's the thing. I was supposed to answer the following question: "Consider A and B to be two points on the positive X and Y axes respectively. Let C(u,v) be a point in the first quadrant. If D be an arbitrary point, and ABCD make a square, find the area of the square in terms of u and v." I used rotation to quickly find the area. Would this approach be correct?